# What kind of battle that was between Dumbledore and Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

In *Fantastic Beasts: Secrets of Dumbledore* movie,

> Dumbledore and Grindelwald briefly fought during the destruction of Blood Pact. Time slowed down (Blood Pact artifact took a long time to fall down) and both battled like speedsters.

Both are definitely not speedsters. What kind of battle was that? Have we encountered such battles before similar to that of mirror dimension battles in Doctor Strange movies?

Comment: The kind of canon-break battle 

Comment: *As Grindelwald’s spell strikes the SHIMMERING SHIELD OF LIGHT, we follow his gaze up the path of the spell and discover his and Dumbledore’s spells have knotted together. [snip] For a moment, they remain like this, connected, each draining the power of the other, the world in suspension. Then: The troth’s CHAIN SHATTERS, sending the CRYSTAL slowly spinning to the ground. Grindelwald and Dumbledore watch as the light from the troth begins to FLICKER, and with a FLASH, everything goes suddenly silent... The world goes slowly STILL, as if the rotation of the earth itself were slowing.*

Comment: *Their spells evaporate. Grindelwald’s and Dumbledore’s eyes meet, both realizing in the same moment that they have been emancipated. Instantly, their wands rise, FLASHING again and again—fire and parry, fire and parry—in a dizzying—and cathartic—display of power. As they continue to battle, they draw closer and closer [snip] the blood troth strikes the floor. CRACK. It breaks in two, and smoke rises from its center . . . The world begins to rotate on its axis once more, the figures surrounding Grindelwald and Dumbledore coming back to life.*

Comment: It's honestly not clear from the "screenplay" what's actually going on in this scene. Like most of this film series, the whole thing is an incoherent bunch of stuff that happens and eventually stops happening.

Answer (score 1):

#### It is unlikely they were actually moving like that- the action was most likely slowed down for *the viewer* so it would be clearer what was happening.

The battle between Dumbledore and Grindelwald most likely did not actually take place in slow motion. Instead, it seems to have been slowed down so the audience of the movie can see what is happening more clearly. While in a book, complicated actions can be described for as long as necessary to explain them, in a movie, it is sometimes necessary to slow down the action so viewers can see the details of what is happening.

Comment: The Blood Pact artifact took forever to fall… all during the battle.